# I have two tables that are associated through some key. i need to write a query to get data from both the tables based on certain condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

The tables structure is given below. First table is subusage and next is machinesubusage.Both are associated with sub_usage_id column. I need to select subusage.product_key and its associated usage count, if subusage.is_standalone is not null then i need to get the associated usage count from subusage.usage_count else associated usage count will be number of rows  in machinesubusage table for that sub_usage_id. I have written queries for both the cases below. I tried case and if statements to combine these two queries but in vain

```
SELECT SU.product_key,COUNT(*) FROM SubUsage SU
INNER JOIN MachineSubUsage MSU ON MSU.sub_usage_id = SU.sub_usage_id
WHERE SU.acct_id = 40897342 GROUP BY SU.product_key

SELECT SU.product_key, SU.usage_count FROM SubUsage SU
INNER JOIN MachineSubUsage MSU ON MSU.sub_usage_id = SU.sub_usage_id
WHERE SU.acct_id = 40897342 GROUP BY SU.product_key, SU.usage_count
```

Tables' structures:

[image]

Comment: What is the case statement you tried and what did you not like about it?

Comment: SELECT SU.product_key, 
 CASE WHEN SU.is_standalone IS NOT NULL THEN  SU.usage_count
 ELSE COUNT(*) END 
 FROM SubUsage SU
INNER JOIN MachineSubUsage MSU ON MSU.sub_usage_id = SU.sub_usage_id
WHERE SU.acct_id = 40897342 GROUP BY SU.product_key, SU.usage_count something on these line but i know this is wrong and wont even compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  SU.product_key,
  SUM(CASE 
        WHEN su.is_standalone IS NOT NULL THEN su.usage_count
        ELSE MSU.SubUsageCount
      END) AS TotalCount
FROM SubUsage SU
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT sub_usage_id, COUNT(*) AS SubUsageCount
   FROM  MachineSubUsage
   GROUP BY sub_usage_id
) AS MSU ON MSU.sub_usage_id = SU.sub_usage_id
WHERE SU.acct_id = 40897342 
GROUP BY SU.product_key;
```

If you need to include those product key that has no match in the other table, use `LEFT JOIN` instead with `ISNULL()` to replace null's with zeros:

```
SELECT 
  SU.product_key,
  SUM(CASE 
        WHEN su.is_standalone IS NOT NULL THEN su.usage_count
        ELSE ISNULL(MSU.SubUsageCount, 0)
      END) AS TotalCount
FROM SubUsage SU
LEFT JOIN
(
   SELECT sub_usage_id, COUNT(*) AS SubUsageCount
   FROM  MachineSubUsage
   GROUP BY sub_usage_id
) AS MSU ON MSU.sub_usage_id = SU.sub_usage_id
WHERE SU.acct_id = 40897342 
GROUP BY SU.product_key;
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to do a SUM as well, your subquery already has the data.

Comment: @twoleggedhorse Yes, you are right, if there is only one entry for each `sub_usage_id` in the second table. But if there are multiple rows for each one, then you will need to count them, the count in this case will be the sum of the two counts. Not sure really if this what he is looking for or not. Waiting for the OP to decide .

Comment: There will be multiple entries for sub_usage_id in machinesubusage table.

Answer (score 0):

In SQLServer2005+ try this request

```
SELECT DISTINCT SU.product_key, SU.usage_count, 
       COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY SU.product_key) 
FROM SubUsage SU JOIN MachineSubUsage MSU ON MSU.sub_usage_id = SU.sub_usage_id
WHERE SU.acct_id = 40897342
```

Answer (score 0):

Mahmoud Gamal has posted what appears to be a good answer.  I'm going to explain what went wrong with the original case statement in the comment by amit.  Here it is:

```
SELECT SU.product_key
, CASE WHEN SU.is_standalone IS NOT NULL THEN SU.usage_count ELSE COUNT(*) END 
FROM SubUsage SU INNER JOIN MachineSubUsage MSU ON MSU.sub_usage_id = SU.sub_usage_id 
WHERE SU.acct_id = 40897342 
GROUP BY SU.product_key, SU.usage_count
```

The problem, which should have shown up in the error message, is that SU.is_standalone is included in the select clause but not in the group by clause.  In fact, if you make that simple correction, you might get the answer you sought.